AWS Lambda Exporting RDS Snapshot to S3 Fails with KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault - Permissions Issue
I have two AWS Lambda functions that automate the process of taking an Amazon RDS (Aurora) snapshot and exporting it to an S3 bucket for cold storage. The first Lambda function creates the RDS snapshot and sends an event to AWS EventBridge. Upon snapshot creation completion, the second Lambda function is triggered by an EventBridge rule and exports the snapshot to S3. The exported snapshot can then be transitioned to S3 Glacier using an S3 lifecycle policy for long-term storage.
I'm facing a KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault error when the second Lambda function tries to export the snapshot to S3.
Lambda Code:
1st Lambda Function (Creates Snapshot) in python:
import boto3
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
eventbridge_client = boto3.client('events')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    db_cluster_identifier = 'staging-aurora'
    
    # Convert UTC to IST
    utc_time = datetime.utcnow()
    ist_time = utc_time + timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
    snapshot_identifier = f"cold-storage-snapshot-{ist_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}"
    
    try:
        # Create Aurora DB Cluster Snapshot
        create_snapshot_response = rds_client.create_db_cluster_snapshot(
            DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_identifier,
            DBClusterIdentifier=db_cluster_identifier
        )
        
        # Send snapshot identifier to EventBridge
        eventbridge_response = eventbridge_client.put_events(
            Entries=[
                {
                    'Source': 'my.rds.snapshot',
                    'DetailType': 'RDSSnapshotCreated',
                    'Detail': json.dumps({
                        'snapshot_identifier': snapshot_identifier,
                        'db_cluster_identifier': db_cluster_identifier
                    }),
                    'EventBusName': 'default'
                }
            ]
        )
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'message': f"Snapshot {snapshot_identifier} creation initiated and event sent to EventBridge.",
                'createSnapshotResponse': create_snapshot_response,
                'eventbridgeResponse': eventbridge_response
            })
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'message': str(e)})
        }

2nd Lambda Function in python (Exports Snapshot to S3):
import boto3
import json

rds_client = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshot_identifier = event['detail']['SourceIdentifier']  # Snapshot ID from EventBridge
    s3_bucket_name = 'cold-storage-sample'
    kms_key_id = 'arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:key/<key-id>'  # Placeholder for KMS Key ARN
    iam_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/RDS-Snapshot-Export-Role'  # Placeholder for IAM Role ARN

    try:
        # Export Snapshot to S3
        export_task_response = rds_client.start_export_task(
            ExportTaskIdentifier=f"export-task-{snapshot_identifier}",
            SourceArn=f"arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:cluster-snapshot:{snapshot_identifier}",
            S3BucketName=s3_bucket_name,
            IamRoleArn=iam_role_arn,
            KmsKeyId=kms_key_id
        )
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'message': f"Export task started for snapshot {snapshot_identifier}.",
                'exportTaskResponse': export_task_response
            })
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'message': f"Error in exporting snapshot to S3: {str(e)}"
            })
        }

The Problem:
When I trigger the second Lambda function (which exports the RDS snapshot to S3), I consistently get the following error:
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "{\"message\": \"Error in exporting snapshot to S3: An error occurred (KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault) when calling the StartExportTask operation: The specified KMS key [arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:key/<key-id>] does not exist, is not enabled or you do not have permissions to access it.\"}"
}

What I Have Checked So Far:

KMS Key Status:

The KMS key is in the Enabled state.

I have verified the correct ARN is being used in the Lambda function (arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:key/<key-id>).



IAM Role Policy for Lambda (RDS-Snapshot-Export-Role):

I have attached the following policy to the Lambda’s IAM role:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "rds:StartExportTask",
        "rds:DescribeExportTasks",
        "rds:ListTagsForResource"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:key/<key-id>"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::cold-storage-sample",
        "arn:aws:s3:::cold-storage-sample/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}





KMS Key Policy:

I have also updated the KMS key policy to allow access to the Lambda’s IAM role:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow Full Access to Lambda Role",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/RDS-Snapshot-Export-Role"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:key/<key-id>"
    }
  ]
}





Region Consistency:

The Lambda function, KMS key, S3 bucket, and RDS snapshot are all in the same region: ap-southeast-1.



Question:
Despite following the documentation and ensuring that the KMS key and IAM role permissions are correct, I’m still getting the KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault error. Could I be missing something specific related to permissions or configuration? How can I further debug or resolve this issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Looks like you're missing the kms:CreateGrant in KMS key policy and you should allow these actions to the service principal export.rds.amazonaws.com.
You can check the db cluster snapshot export documentation and Encryption keys with Aurora documentationfor more details but the main points:

Create a symmetric encryption AWS KMS key
The KMS key policy must include both the kms:CreateGrant and kms:DescribeKey permission
If you have a deny statement in your KMS key policy, make sure to explicitly exclude the AWS service principal export.rds.amazonaws.com

